# Does setDataFormatForType() work correctly for Dates in XLConnect?

Tags: r, apache-poi, xlconnect

I recently tried all sorts of formatting arguments on the function

```
setDataFormatForType(wb, type=XLC$DATA_TYPE.DATETIME, format="d/m/yy")
```

for example format="d/m/yy" as shown above, besides numerous others.

This then is followed up by

```
setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATA_FORMAT_ONLY")
```

and then I write a worksheet and save the workook. 
No form of format tweaking seems to work. 
As soon as I mess with any format in the setDataFormatForType command the result is that the numeric time value shows up in the date columns in Excel workbook that I save later on 
i.e. for Nov. 6th, 2013 = 41584. 
If I do not interfere with any DataFormats then Standard (POSIX) format gets saved but when you look at that in the resulting Excel it has some Custom "XLConnect format" assigned to it so it is displayed "wrong" :-( 
- which means American notation (leading month followed by day) but what I want is Eurepean (leading day followed by the month).

If anyone has some experience with setting these DataFormats (especially 'dates') in XLConnect, then sharing some thoughts or wisdom would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, Walter

Comment: You might want to submit this as a possible bug. I certainly had the same experience as you.

Comment: I should have mentioned that bug reports go to the package maintainer: `maintainer('XLConnect')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a new style action `XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATATYPE"` in the XLConnect version available from github at https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect. The "datatype" style action can be used to style cells of a specific type using a specific cell style which can be set using `setCellStyleForType`. See the following example:

```
require(XLConnect)
wb = loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create = TRUE)
setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATATYPE")
cs = createCellStyle(wb, name = "mystyle")
setDataFormat(cs, format = "d/m/yy")
setCellStyleForType(wb, style = cs, type = XLC$"DATA_TYPE.DATETIME")
data = data.frame(A = 1:10, B = Sys.time() + 1:10)
createSheet(wb, "data")
writeWorksheet(wb, data = data, sheet = "data")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do need to have a named region called "Dates". I saved a copy of the template2.xslx file with such a region. The only think that worked for me was to write it out with the `format.Date` function:

```
Dates=seq(from=as.Date("2001-01-01"), to=as.Date("2013-01-01"), by=365)
file.copy(system.file("demoFiles/template2.xlsx", 
                      package = "XLConnect"),
          "dataformat.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
wb <- loadWorkbook("dataformat.xlsx")
setDataFormatForType(wb, type = XLC$"DATA_TYPE.DATETIME", 
                     format = "dd/mm/yyyy")
setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATA_FORMAT_ONLY")
createName(wb, name = "Dates", formula = "mtcars!$A$1")
writeNamedRegion(wb, format(Dates, "%d.%m.%Y"), name = "Dates")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: I did something similar to resolve my problem … i.e. defined a Custom format Date_ and then applied that with SetCellStyle to the respective columns.   
Thank you very much for sharing your solution approach.

Comment: You should add an answer and accept it. That's perfectly accepted on SO. Encouraged even. I tried find a "custom" format since that is the "language" used in the Excel interface, but I could not find anything in the X:Connect documentation that supported a custom type.

Comment: When I say Custom Format I mean that I went for defining my "own" style via createCellStyle and then calling setCellStyle.

Comment: by the way - your code as shown in this post does not work. 
Since the named region you are trying to write to does not exist it results in 'Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Name 'Dates' does not exist!'

Comment: I just inserted 
createName(wb, name = "Dates", formula = "mtcars!$A$1") ... 
to heal that. Hope it's ok?

Comment: Your edit was being held up for review and for reasons that puzzle me was getting more 'reject' votes than 'approve', so I just it in. Thanks.