# Exporting date data to .xlsx file with XLConnect (R) bug?

Tags: r, excel, date, xlconnect

UPDATE 2: Example that is producing problem.

Example Excel File: is a blank .xlsx with a sheet name Sheet1.
Example R Code:

```
library(chron)
library(rJava)
library(xlsxjars)
library(xlsx)
library(XLConnect)

setwd("C:/")

Day<-as.Date('2014-01-01')
Data<-as.data.frame(rep(Day,35))

name<-paste("Example.xls")
Master<-loadWorkbook(name, create=TRUE)
writeWorksheet(object=Master, data=Data,sheet="Sheet1", startRow=2, startCol=1,header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(Master)
```

UPDATE:
The numeric value in the data frame for "12/31/2013" is 16070. The last date is "3/25/2014" with a value of 16154.

This is expected. However, when I look at the numbers written to the sheet, "12/31/2013" is 41638.75 and should be 41639. "3/25/2014" is 41722.79 and should be 41723.

Am I missing something about how an R data frame interprets a whole date? Does the Java Routine subtract a certain fraction of a whole number?

ORIGINAL:
I am attempting to export many data frames to different sheets of an .xlsx file. My data frame has date only data information in a data frame. (i.e. **"2013-12-31"** )

I use the following code to export it to my excel file.

```
Temp<-data
name<-paste("Master.xlsx") 
Master<-loadWorkbook(name, create=TRUE)
writeWorksheet(object=Master,data=Temp,sheet="Ft. Wayne",startRow = 2, startCol = 1,   header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(Master)
```

When I open the .xlsx file, the date comes in as:

**12/30/2013 18:00:00**

How do I get to to export with the format

**"12/31/2013"**

And maintain "date" cell number formatting the.xlsx file?

FYI: If I change the format in the dataframe, it exports as a "general" value.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865890/does-setdataformatfortype-work-at-all-for-dates-in-xlconnect help?

Comment: I have updated my question. This solution did not solve the subtracted time issue I am having.

Comment: Could you post a complete reproducible example including the data? Also, could you provide the output of sessionInfo() in R, the version of Java you are using and the time zone you are in?

Comment: sessionInfo()R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XLConnect_0.2-7 xlsx_0.5.5      xlsxjars_0.6.0  rJava_0.9-6    
[5] chron_2.3-45    RODBC_1.3-10   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.3

Comment: java version: "1.6.0_11" and time zone: US CST

Comment: I have updated the orginial post with an example producing the same behavior.

Comment: @MartinStuder, if you have not already please see above, I realize I did not tag my responses.

Comment: @hrbrmstr  please see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason for this behavior is that objects of class `Date` are converted internally to `POSIXct` and are assumed to represent a date at midnight UTC. US CST is UTC - 6 hours so that's why you experience an offset. I would suggest you use `POSIXct` directly. If you want to display dates without time components in Excel, you can use cell styles and data formats.

Example:

```r
library(XLConnect)

data = data.frame(Day = rep(as.POSIXct('2014-01-01'), 35))

wb = loadWorkbook("example.xls", create = TRUE)

setStyleAction(wb, XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.DATATYPE")
cs = createCellStyle(wb, name = "myDateStyle")
setDataFormat(cs, format = "yyyy-mm-dd")
setCellStyleForType(wb, style = cs, type = XLC$"DATA_TYPE.DATETIME")

createSheet(wb, name = "test")
writeWorksheet(wb, data = data, sheet = "test", startRow = 2, startCol = 1, header = FALSE)

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did that is a significantly less amount of code which might work for you, is converting your date column to a character before exporting it to Excel.

I am working with data in R and want to export it with the XLConnect package so what I did before exporting the data frame is simply change the date column from a date format to a character and it looks much cleaner upon opening in Excel.

Instead of getting this in Excel:
12/30/2013 18:00:00

I get : "12/31/2013"